# SQL left join on column ignoring first letter

Tags: sql, database, netezza

I’m trying to left join 2 tables using ‘order id’ from table a and ‘order ref’ from table b.

The problem is where order is would be totally numeric ‘12345’ the order ref would have a letter before the same number ‘a12345’

Wondering if there is a way to do the join but ignoring the letter from table b?

Any ideas welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sure. The things you see in a JOIN are truth statements; they don't have to have anything to do with table data at all

```
A JOIN B ON EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW()) = 12
```

That will join all rows in A with all rows in B but only during one hour per day (you have to run it between 12:00 and 12:59:59) - it's nothing to do with the table data

Imagine that joins work like "every row in A is joined with every row in B and then the truth statements are evaluated for every row in the result. If the truth is false the row is discard. Hence an `ON 1=1` is valid and includes all rows because it's is always true..

---

As such joining all rows in A to B where B's is is the one with "a" at the start would be something like:

```
A JOIN B ON A.ID = SUBSTR(B.ID, 2, LENGTH(B.ID) - 1))
```

Careful though; manipulating table data can kill use of indexes

Consider also that you could do `B.ID LIKE CONCAT('_', A.ID)`

Answer (score 1):

If the order ref would *always* have a single letter prefix to the order id, then just join on the substring of the former:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON SUBSTR(b.order_ref, 2, LENGTH(b.order_ref) - 1) = a.order_id;
```

If the order ref might or might not have that single letter prefix, you could try joining on either condition:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON b.order_ref = a.order_id OR
       SUBSTR(b.order_ref, 2, LENGTH(b.order_ref) - 1) = a.order_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using regexp_* suite of functions to help out.

Eg

```sql
select * 
from A left join B 
on 
   regexp_extract(A.order_id, ‘^\D*(\d+)’, 1) =
   regexp_extract(B.order_ref, ‘^\D*(\d+)’, 1);
```

In this case `\D*` indicates zero or more occurrences of non-digit characters, followed by one or more digits that are captured by the enclosed parenthesis. This let’s you ignore no digit prefixes, if any, during the join